# Live sound synthesis in Javascript: any way to reduce latency?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm developing a Javascript music app.

Offline rendering works fine, i.e. generate a buffer, play it at a given time using an AudioBufferSourceNode. Timing is almost perfect.

But I need to generate tones that cannot be created using the default nodes of the API. So I put my sound generating logic inside the callback of a ScriptProcessorNode.

I'm fairly certain that the code in my ScriptProcessorNode is fast enough, because once started the sound plays without a glitch for any number of buffer periods that I want - so filling the buffer in time is probably not the issue here. From my experiments I figured out that the onaudioprocess event of the ScriptProcessorNode is fired at regular intervals, not depending on when the processor node was created. This creates unpredictable latency in the app: if the user presses a key right after a callback has started then it waits till the next period to play.

I've created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sw3hF/44/) to demonstrate it. There is a simple instrument and two buttons to control it. One plays a pre-recorded buffer:

```
function playBuffer()
{
    source = ac.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(ac.destination);
    source.start(0);
};
```

and the other one plays the same sound but live:

```
function playLive()
{
    processor = ac.createScriptProcessor(4096, 0, 1);
    processor.onaudioprocess = function(e)
    {
        sineStrument.fillBuffer(e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0), e.outputBuffer.length);
    }
    processor.connect(ac.destination);
};
```

Using the first button you can generate a rhythm and hear that it works flawlessly. Using the second button you can't because it takes around 50+ms for the sound to start.

Now notice that the instrument is really simple, I don't think I have a speed of computation issue here. Plus, if you time it right, you can get the live processed sound to play in sync with your clicks - I figure you "only" need to click just before the onaudioprocess callback is called.

The facts that 1) the playBuffer function plays immediately and 2) it is possible to get the correct timing with the playLive function tell me that there should be a technical way to get a ScriptProcessorNode timed right.

How can I do it? How come playing a buffer doesn't have fixed starting times?

I've tried reducing the buffer size of the ScriptProcessorNode too, but sound gets distorted very quickly. Why is it so? If the code in the callback wasn't fast enough wouldn't the sound have glitches after a while? It does not!

Comment: The buffer latency is most likely related to the latency of your sound card as the browser is not able to utilize low-latency drivers such as ASIO this is to be expected. The pre-generated sample can be queued up for the buffers while the live one is generated to the *current* buffer (which is, without checking, probably double or triple buffered which induce latency).

Answer (score -1):

Connect your ScriptProcessorNode to a GainNode with gain value initialized to 0. Make the "Play Live" button set the gain value to 1 when pressed, 0 when released.